# Melander Drag&Dop - OnClick never executes

Tags: delphi, drag-and-drop

I have a question that is specific to Melander's Drag&Drop (v5.2). I hope this is suitable for StackOverflow. I want to drag some files from a TFileListBox to another control and I use this code to do it:

```
procedure TFrmManager.FileListMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
VAR i: Integer;
begin
 //EXIT;    <-------- 'Exit' makes the OnClik work

 { DRAG BETWEEN INTERNAL CONTROLS }
 if DragDetectPlus(TWinControl(Sender)) then      <------------- HERE IS THE 'BLACKHOLE'
  begin
    Frm1.DropFileSource.Files.Clear;          { Delete anything from a previous drag }
    Frm1.DropFileSource.Files.Add(FileList.Items[0]);
    Frm1.DropFileSource.Execute;               { Start the drag operation }
  end;
end;
```

and then I have some code in FileListBox's OnClick:

```
procedure TFrmManager.FileListClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
 Preview(Sender);   <------ Never executes
end;
```

The thing is that once DragDetectPlus is executed, FileListBox.OnClick never executes. In other words, if I put EXIT at the top of MouseDown procedure, then OnClick works. 
What am I doing wrong?

(I hope I explained the problem well enough).

---

Update: 
I just tried the 'Source demo' demo project provided in Melander's package. After dragging several times files over it, I managed to freeze it and the entire IDE. I have observed this behavior also in my app. So it seems that this great library (I really really really loved it) has some serious issues. So sad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IDE freeze is caused by a bug in the IDE. I reported it during the D2006 or D2007 field test so it's no surprise that it hasn't been fixed yet.

The cause of the problem is a debugger deadlock. There's some code in one of the units (`DropSource` AFAIR) to work around it by basically disabling the IDE as a drop target while your application is being debugged. It's using some undocumented Windows stuff and I can't remember if it's enabled by default so you'll have to dig a bit yourself. Which version of Delphi and Windows are you using BTW?

WRT your original problem, you can't both detect the start of a drag (with either `DragDetect` or `DragDetectPlus`) *and* expect to have `OnClick` fire. `DragDetect*` works by reading mouse move and up/down messages from the Windows message queue. The same messages that are used to generate the `OnClick` event (specifically `WM_LBUTTONUP` message).

The regular `DragDetect` will remove the messages from the queue while `DragDetectPlus` leaves them on the queue. Regardless which one you use the drag operation itself will alter the content of the message queue so once `DropSource.Execute` returns, the message might no longer be on the queue.

As a work around I suggest you just call your `OnClick` handler directly from the `OnMouseDown` handler.

Comment: @speedfreak-but you said: "while DragDetectPlus leaves them on the queue". And I do use DragDetectPlus.

Comment: Thanks A LOT for the IDE freeze tip. I try to write stable applications and every time I see a bug like this I blame firstly MY code, thinking that Embarcadero guys are doing 10 better code than mine.

Comment: @Altar `DragDetectPlus` uses [`PeekMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644943%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the `PM_NOREMOVE` flag for mouse click messages which means that the messages gets left on the queue. It does however remove mouse movement and keyboard messages.  What happens if you just click (mouse button down, mouse button up) without moving the mouse. Does that make a difference?

Comment: "Does that make a difference?" - No